# How to instance geometry rather than Objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to reverse engineer the awesome setup of Felipe del Rio [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/little-town-with-geometry-nodes/1300974).

I got as far as setting up an XY array with geometry nodes that instances objects using Line primitives. I want to repeat the XY output on the Z-axis, creating the basic shape of a building.

I am looking for a way to 'chain' the XY-axis output, but there are currently no nodes that instance Geometry directly (Blender 3.0 alpha). How would I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found Felipe del Rio's solution on developer.blender.org: https://developer.blender.org/project/view/121/

Felipe uses the Grid primitive, which gives you a 2d array option. No 'chaining' required.

I'll wait for further developments to see if instancing geometry becomes an option.